# Array#uniq with block equivalent in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.8

[Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) has this behaviour in Ruby 1.9

```
c = [ "a:def", "a:xyz", "b:abc", "b:xyz", "c:jkl" ]
c.uniq {|s| s[/^\w+/]}  #=> [ "a:def", "b:abc", "c:jkl" ]
```

It can take a block and give unique value with respect to what we give. But, this wont work in Ruby 1.8. How can I create this functionality in ruby 1.8?

Comment: Why do yo want to use Ruby 1.8? It is going to become obsolete.

Comment: @sawa: Perhaps he already has a project using 1.8 and no budget or time to upgrade right now.

Comment: Or is on a machine where he is not allowed to upgrade it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [Marc-André LaFortune's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andre-lafortune) backports gem:

> https://github.com/marcandre/backports

That has the block versions of 1.9.2's `Array#uniq` and `Array#uniq!`. Or if you don't want or need the whole thing, the parts are pretty well isolated so you can pull out just the pieces you need:

> https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/1.9.2/array.rb#L99

Comment: aahh..this was mentioned by marc himself in one of my other questions..how did I forget that...thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to implement something like:

```
class Array
    def uniq
        ret, keys = [], []
        each do |x|
            key = block_given? ? yield(x) : x
            unless keys.include? key
                ret << x
                keys << key
            end
        end
        ret
    end
end
```