# Remove similar objects from array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{ item_id: 1, relationship_1: 1, relationship_2: 1, value: 'go' },
 { item_id: 2, relationship_1: 2, relationship_2: 2, value: 'stop' },
 { item_id: 3, relationship_1: 2, relationship_2: 1, value: 'stop' }, #remove
 { item_id: 4, relationship_1: 3, relationship_2: 1, value: 'go' },
 { item_id: 5, relationship_1: 1, relationship_2: 2, value: 'go' }] #remove
```

I want the lines commented to be removed. The need is to remove all lines that have `relationship_1` and `value` in common. The only way I can think of is:

```
items.each do |i|
  items.each do |k|
    if i.item_id != k.item_id and i.relationship_1 == k.relationship_1 and i.value == k.value
      items.remove(k)
    end
  end
end
```

This is not working as intended. What is the most "Ruby" way to remove those offending items?

Comment: How do you define "similar"? Also please read about [the difference between `&&`/`||` & `and`/`or` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/). They are **not** the same.

Comment: In this case I mean by having a specific set of values that are equal, there wasn't really a better way to word it in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`uniq_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by) isn't available in Ruby core. Pull it in with `require 'activesupport'`.

```
items.uniq_by {|h| [h[:replationship_1], h[:value]] }
```

**Edit**: As noted by @mu below, Ruby 1.9's [`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) also works:

```
items.uniq{|h| [h[:replationship_1], h[:value]] }
```

Comment: Fortunately I am using Rails 3. I didn't want extra requirements if it didn't need them. Seeing as these objects are ActiveResource objects, this will work great. Thank you.

Comment: [The implementation of `uniq_by`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7194b393a611727fb36e8f586910e75db1bae746/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/uniq_by.rb#L6) is (i think) actually rather clever and worthy of inspection.

Comment: Nonsense, sort of. 1.9's [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) can take a block and `Array#uniq` certainly is in the core.

Comment: @muistooshort I thought it did, but I was surprised when I looked at the docs and the method's signature doesn't state it takes a block so I didn't even bother to look at the examples. (Thankfully this doc issue is fixed in [Ruby trunk](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L3608).)

Comment: @muistooshort Good call. Didn't know that.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall (and Austin): To be fair, the documentation isn't exactly clear and explicit, nice to see that it is being fixed.

Answer (score 3):

`group_by{ |item| [item.relationship_1, item.value] }.values.map(&:first)`?

**UPDATE**

Oops, it was a hash:

`group_by{ |item| [item[:relationship_1], item[:value]] }.values.map(&:first)`

or

`group_by{ |item| item.values_at(:relationship_1, :value) }.values.map(&:first)`

Comment: why `item.relationship_1` dosen't work on my ruby 1.9.2 install? I must make `item[:relationship_1]` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by) function will help. I found it mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653508/arrayuniq-with-block-equivalent-in-ruby-1-8-7), and if I am not wrong it is part of latest ruby on rails.

```
a.uniq_by {|t| [t.replationship_1, t.value]}
```