# Difference in output between Ruby versions when running script

Tags: ruby, shell, irb

I have the following script in ruby:

```
set = []
for i in 2..100 
  for j in 2..100
    set << i**j
  end 
end
puts set.uniq!.count
```

When running this script with Ruby version `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]`, the output is 8243.

When I run this script with Ruby version `ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]`, the output is 9183 (which is what I expect the result to be).

Any ideas why there is a discrepancy between the two versions?

Comment: I ran your code using the exact same build (1.8.7 patchlevel 358), albeit on a newer OS X (Mavericks=13.0.0) and got 9183.  Also tried a one-liner to see if it made a difference, but it did not ( `set = (2..100).inject([]) { |a,i| (2..100).inject(a) { |a,j| a << i**j  } }.uniq` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get same results for both version (1.8, 1.9.3)

```
$ ruby1.8 --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-linux]
$ ruby1.9.3 --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
$ ruby1.8 t.rb
9183
$ ruby1.9.3 t.rb
9183
```

BTW, chaining `uniq!` with `count` is not a good idea, because `uniq!` returns nil if there's no duplicate.

Comment: Hmmmm this is really weird. I just tried it again, running the same commands as you, and I still get 8243 for the old version and 9183 for the newer version...

Comment: @karkum, What do you get with  `puts set.size` just before call `uniq!` ? It should be `9801`.

Comment: Yep, it is 9801. You think it has to do something with the implementation of `uniq`?

Comment: @karkum, It's interesting. I ran it with the exactly same version (1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358)) as you. (except OS).

Comment: Yes it is. I'm not too worried about it, 1.8 will be obsolete soon. [Here is a similar question that might explain it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653508/arrayuniq-with-block-equivalent-in-ruby-1-8-7)